# Change template of an existing site to team

Tags: office-365, site

**Now:**
I have a (root) site with template "publishing".
I am using SharePoint 365 Online

**Goal:**
Change template of the existing site to "team"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. Site templates just provides different features and page layouts enabled based on template type. So what you have to do is activate all features required. But what specific feature you are looking in team site. As per my understanding all the features available in team site is by default available in publishing site. But it is not true for reverse case, all features in publishing site is not available in team site. But by enabling some features on team site we can publishing site features and functionality.

So to do reverse like publishing site to team site, you would need to deactivate some features. Page layouts of publishing site, you can delete manually from gallery. List and Libaries again you can delete manually.

Comment: I'd like to add quick links web part as tiles/grid. This seems to be possible only in team template (in publishing quick links don't have such setting).
Actually anything that could replace the old promoted links from SP2013 would be great - I simply need links to libraries presented nicely on the main page.

Is there a way to do that in publishing site?

Comment: Can you check if 'Add an app' gives you option to add promoted links..they way it see it you need to create list of type Promoted links and then can be used as webpart.

Comment: I did check that - it is not possible to add promoted links. Something like a 'Hero' web part, which is available in sharepoint online 365 would be great too, but it seems like it is not possible to use it in publishing template. Unless maybe there is a workaround, perhaps using sharepoint developer

Comment: yes...then customization would be required...if you need help do let me know.. i will still check from my side what would be optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a modern site page in this template. Then all modern web parts, including Quick Links and Hero part can be added easily.

To enable Site Pages:
Activate Site Settings > Manage site features > Site Pages > Activate Add modern pages by going to Site Contents > Site Pages > New > Site Page
(It might take some time for the new setting to kick in)